# Add incremented number to string

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add a number to the end of a string.

eg.

> john1
>
> beth2
>
> mike3
>
> mary4

```
class finalName
{
   public string name(string initialName)
      {
      string finalName = string.Empty;
      for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      {
          finalName = initialName + i.ToString("0");                    
       }
         return finalName;
   }
}

finalName name = new finalName();
```

The result that I am getting is:

> jonh9
>
> beth9
>
> mike9
>
> mary9

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are returning after the loop is completed. And at end of the loop you will have i = 9 that's why you are getting that behavior. Can you share how are you calling this method?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I edited to add the class. The names are coming from a text file. I missed it when I copied it the first time.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question - Who calls `code.ame` method? Can you share the code which reads names from file and calls this method?

Comment: Sorry. I can't seem to copy today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just looping inside the method and returns the last value.

If you want each call of the function to add an incremented number, then add this `counter` as a field in your class and add it to the string:

```
int counter = 1;
public string name(string initialName)
{
    return initialName + counter++;
}
```

If you are creating a new instance every call, then the variable should be made `static`:

```
static int counter = 1;
public string name(string initialName)
{
    return initialName + counter++;
}
```

If you would like to send in a list of strings to the function and get back the list with an incremented number then you should first change the signature to get a collection and return a collection:

```
public IEnumerable<string> name(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    return names.Select( (s,i) => s+(i+1));    
}
```

Comment: Well, i'm not familiar with your code, but if you are creating a new instance every time, it won't work. you will have to change the field to `static` or keep using the same instance

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is modify your method so it takes a collection of names, then modifies those with an incrementing indexer:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ModifyNames(IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    int index = 1;

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        yield return name + index;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLKHLL)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove for loop from your `name` function. 
Your loop always ends with `i` equal to 9 and result is always `initialName` + 9.

I think that you need something like this:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "john", "beth", "mike", "mary" };

for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = names[i] + (i + 1).ToString();
}
```